# Grails and DAO layer concept

Tags: grails, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, grails-orm, dao

I'm using grails with GORM.

I'm kinda confused with grails : I can't find simple example where it's explained how to reuse queries via a DAO layer.

Is the concept of dao layer not present in grails ?
How to reuse queries between services ?
What is the best practice in grails ? Named queries ? Or else ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Grails Best Practises](http://www.infoq.com/articles/grails-best-practices):

> Domain
>
> 2. To reuse common partial queries or decompose the complex logic, use named queries and chain them together as required, just like one
>      commonly chains jQuery function calls.

Comment: Where do you put these named queries ? (in which file ?) For example if you have a named query about users, but as a parameter you another domain class instance like TeamInstance. Where do you put this named query which return user but manage an other domain class as a parameter.

Comment: In domain class files (inside grails-app/domain). More sophisticated logic put inside services (inside grails-app/services).